# Sceneform Child nodes move relative to parent when rotating phone

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

In HelloSceneform, when replacing these lines ...

```
          TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
      andy.setParent(anchorNode);
      andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
      andy.select();
```

... with these lines, and start the application.

```
  Texture.builder()
      .setSource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.boardbackground)
      .build()
      .thenAccept(backtexture ->
          MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithTexture(getApplicationContext(), backtexture)
              .thenAccept(backmaterial -> {
                ModelRenderable backrenderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(1f, 0.01f, 1f), Vector3.zero(), backmaterial);

                Node background = new Node();
                background.setLocalPosition(Vector3.up());
                background.setParent(anchorNode);
                background.setRenderable(backrenderable);


                Texture.builder()
                    .setSource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.img_20180609_115300)
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(texture ->
                        MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithTexture(getApplicationContext(), texture)
                            .thenAccept(material -> {
                              ModelRenderable renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.01f, 0.5f), Vector3.zero(), material);

                              Node foreground = new Node();
                              foreground.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.2f, 0.1f, 0f));
                              foreground.setParent(background);
                              foreground.setRenderable(renderable);
                            })
                    );

              })
      );
```

This results in [the following effect](https://photos.app.goo.gl/DA7gt1QZZMjLgQXf8): Even when the child node is above the parent node, rotating the phone leads to the child being moved to the back of the parent node.

This happens when either the center or the local position of the child node has a value different to 0.

This problem was reported first to ARCore in July, then reported to Sceneform end of August, still gets completely ignored by both teams. That way ARCore is completely unusable for me. Any idea to get this solved is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is, to set the rendering priority manually with `Renderable.setRenderPriority`. This happens even when the parent and child are 50cm appart and a parent-child relation exists.